# Random Translation in D3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to append 'g' in random locations within an svg. Below is my code. Surprisingly, all the 10 'g's are being drawn on the same position. I specified random position in line 5 but all g got the same x and y. What am I doing wrong?

```
const art = svg.selectAll('g')
.data(d3.range(10))
.enter()
.append('g')
.attr("transform", `translate(${d3.randomInt(padding, width-padding)()},${d3.randomInt(padding, height-padding)()})`) //this line
.selectAll('snowflake')
.data(d3.range(6))
.enter()
.append('line')
.style("stroke", "lightblue")
.style("stroke-width", 5)
.attr("x1", 0)
.attr("y1", 0)
.attr("x2", d=>r*Math.cos(d*Math.PI/3))
.attr("y2", d=>r*Math.sin(d*Math.PI/3))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the second parameter of `.attr()` or `.style()` is a function, `.attr()`/`.style()` will execute it once for every element in the selection. If the second parameter evaluates to be a string or a number (some constant value), that constant value will be passed to `.attr()`/`.style()`. Either way, the `.attr()` and `.style()` are called only once.

Your code falls into the second case: you aren't passing a function to `.attr()`, you are passing a single string:

```
`translate(${d3.randomInt(padding, width-padding)()},${d3.randomInt(padding, height-padding)()})`
```

You cannot pass this line of code unevaluated to any method or function, it must be evaluated and then passed to the `.attr()` method. As the `.attr()` method is called only once, you only get one random number.

If you had created a function to get you your random string:

```
 function random() {
      return `translate(${d3.randomInt(padding, width-padding)()},${d3.randomInt(padding, height-padding)()})`
 }
```

You are doing the equivalent of:

```
select.attr("translate", random()); // pass the return value to .attr (a string)
```

But what you want to be doing is passing the function itself:

```
select.attr("translate", random);  // pass the function itself to .attr so it can execute it
```

This method is still only executed once, but internally it will call `random` for each element in the selection.

So you can do like the above, or use an anonymous function:

```
 selection.attr("translate",function() { /* return random translate */ })
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. You not only gave the answer but also pointed out where the problem was. Thanks again!